# How to add array inside an array in Joi validator for mongoose schema?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongoose, joi

I'm getting this error while compiling the code `node index`.

```
Invalid schema configuration: `undefined` is not a valid type within the array `location`.
```

When I add this to the Joi validation schema, I get the error.

```
joi.array().items(joi.array().items(joi.number().integer())).default([]),
```

The array that I want to validate,

```
{
  // other fields..
  location: [[1,32,145], [0,1,null]],
  // other field 
}
```

I have tried other iterations to figure out what causes the error.

```
joi.array().items().default([]) // No error
joi.array().items(joi.number().integer()) // No error
joi.array().items(joi.array().items()) // This caused error
```

**I think adding an array inside an array is causing the error.**

**IMP NOTE:** Using schema like this, and error around this.

```
new mongoose.Schema(joigoose.convert(PSS), { _id: false, versionKey: false })
```

I have manually added the array inside an array in MongoDB Document, which means this error is with mongoose, as joi allows array inside an array.

Comment: Please share the payload against which this schema was tested

Comment: Error is coming when I'm trying to build/compile the code [node index], not against any payload.

Comment: Tested this schema against an empty array `[]` in this fiddle. https://joi.dev/tester/ it did not throw any error.

Comment: https://joi.dev/tester/ is not giving an error. It runs fine there. But when I put the same schema to pass to joigoose for mongoose schema, it shows an error?

Comment: Can you share a link where this can be tested online?

Comment: I think the error is with mongoose, do you know any mongoose schema tester/checker?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241780/discussion-between-divyanshu-sahu-and-nitheesh).